# Not able to update the value displayed below listview ,when edittext inside list item is changed

Tags: android, listview

[image]

i want to update the grand total amount when the edittext value inside list become changed.I have tried several events including onfocuschanged listener and textchange listener.But not full filling my needs.i don't need codes but if anyone can advice me with any logic then it will be helpfull.thank you

Comment: can you please show some code how you have implemented?

Comment: You need TextWatcher only to fulfill you requirement, I have developed such app in which serving the same functionality

Comment: Solved your problem ?

Comment: yeah thanks you.But can i ask you something? is there any way to retain the value typed in edittext inside the list,if the user went back to the previous activity and again loaded the cart activity?

Comment: Hope you get it.how can we do it from inside the adapter?

Comment: Then you need to point to one Instance of the data which will be filled in nthe list everytime. and whenever you chaneg the text in the edittext, change the value in that Instance also...Basically You need to work with `DataManager` with a single copy only :)

Comment: Hope you get it....For any confusion or help , You can [join this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **TextWatcher** only to fulfill you requirement, I have developed such app in which I am serving the same functionality.

## Steps :

- Set Quantity of the list item in TextWatcher
- Calculate total amount 
         - Iterate the list and calculate amt = price * quantity
         - Sum up all the amount i.e Grand total
- Return this Grand total the the invoking Activity and setText

## Adapter code :

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int pos = editQtyTag.position;
            if (!s.toString().trim().equals("")) {

                data.get(pos).setQuantiy(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));

                if (mListener instanceof Activity) {
                    ((Activity) mListener).setReturnValue(
                            setAmt());
                }

            }
        }

 public float setAmt() {
    float total = 0;
    // iterate through the list and calculate the total amount

    return total;
}
```

## Activity Code :

```
public void setReturnValue(float amt) {

    mTxtAmt.setText(amt+"");

}
```

Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need the **TextChangedListener** in your so you can change the grand total amount when the edittext value inside list become changed , as follows.

```
    editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);

    // Capture Text in EditText
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String charText = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

          // do stuff what you want with charText 

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```